# Themes who can use with action bar and tabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-tablayout

I need a help about to find a theme who fits in this part of my project, but first I believe is nice to explain first the structure of the activities to find the answer:

[Example of project style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNVBs.png)

- The main activity (left) don't have any Action Bar, because takes to much space from screen an the Action Bar, polluted the design and is useless in this point.
- The main activity, depending on the option of user, can go to 2 others activities, but both of them are kind of the same of the right activity(not eeeequal equal... is just to explain.) that consists in a Action Bar on top with the text of the result, a button back, one fixed part with some informations, and a Tab Layout with 3 tabs, each one, is a fragment.

the problem starts obviously, in this second activity...

I followed this site to build the screen at first: https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

but, with this site, they use this style:

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

But using this style, with what i need, the result is this error:

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
```

So, to try to find the answer, i find this site over here: http://geeksmember.blogspot.com.br/2015/10/errorerror-inflating-class.html

Who shows me this solution on styles file:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="android:Theme.Material">
```

Is a nice solution, is nice because in this moment i can separe the main style from the other style. Ok... buuuuut... when i start the aplication, comes this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

so... that's my question... because, when i use the "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" comes the first error again... and i stay on this situation who i can't find a style who doesn't match with my needs...

If anyone needs the style file... (this is the style file for all the activities except the main activity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base" />

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="***I Need a theme here, i know, this is my question*** :)">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#212121</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#303030</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">#80CBC4</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

### Use a different theme for your two activities

To do this, you'd create an "action bar theme" and a "no action bar theme":

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#212121</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#303030</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then, in your manifest, you'd assign the first theme to your app, and the second theme to any screen you didn't want an action bar for:

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        ...
    </activity>

</application>
```

So this way, all screens will have an action bar by default, but any activity that should not have an action bar can be set up by specifying `AppTheme.NoActionBar` for that single activity.

### Use a toolbar widget when you want an action bar

For this approach, you'd create your app theme to have no action bar:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#212121</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#303030</item>
</style>
```

Then, in any activity that *should* have an action bar, you'd add a `Toolbar` to your activity's layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In your activity's `onCreate()` method, after setting your content view, you'd tell the system to use this toolbar as the action bar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: I Have made the action bar customized worked in other screen, i make a layout and i called in code using: 
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.menu_telas); 
[... rest of code etc...]

Comment: My question is: the toolbar you implemented here is to replace the TabLayout or to replace the Action Bar? i don´t get it...